# How to upgrade @ngrx/store syntax usage from version 2.2.1 to version 6.1.2

Tags: angular, ngrx

How to upgrade @ngrx/store syntax usage from version 2.2.1 to version 6.1.2

Recently I upgrade my Angular project, from Angular ^2.0.0 to Angular ^6.0.0 and related npm plugins. However, I am not familiar with `@ngrx/store` and `immutable` usage. After project upgraded, app basically works. But the following code throws error: `can not read get of undefined`:

```
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';

// .....

    this.modifyState$ = store.select('suitablyInfoModify');
    this.client$ = this.modifyState$.map(data => data.get('client'));

// works on @ngrx/store v2.2.1, immutable v3.8.1
// errors on @ngrx/store v6.1.2, immutable v3.8.2
```

It shows `@ngrx/store` does not transfer `data` in `map` function. The variable `data` is `undefined` now.

So how can I modify this part to get it work? And hope compatible with the original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved!**

Actually the problem was caused by the `StoreModule` config：

```
@NgModules({
  imports: [
    // ...
    // previous i wrote like this
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducer)
  ]
})
```

so that in the store subscrition the data always be `undefined`.

After one-day study, I finally found out that bug, and fixed it already:

```
@NgModules({
  imports: [
    // ...
    // fix it
    StoreModule.forRoot({
      suitablyInfoModify: reducer,
    })
  ]
})
```

Hah, finally~

Thanks to @John's answer which also helps me!

Answer (score 2):

If you navigate to the [ngrx monorepo on github](https://github.com/ngrx/platform), you can view all the documentation for past releases by clicking the "Branch: master" button (located to the far left of the green "Clone or download" button) > selecting the "tags" tab > clicking the tag associated with the app version you are interested in. This will show you the repo as it was for that version, then you'll need to navigate to the documentation for the store (which I think may have moved around in the repo between versions).

Unfortunately, the repo changed between version 2 and version 4 (there was no version 3) so they don't have the version 2 documentation there (I'm not sure where it is). Still, if you compare the documentation for version 4 with the documentation for version 6 of ngrx/store, hopefully that will help you get a sense of what has changed.

One change: rxjs moved to [lettable operators](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-lettable-operators-fe74dda186d3). I'm not sure whether they still allow the `observable.operator()` syntax in version 6 of angular, but in later versions you definitely need to use the lettable operator syntax of `observable.pipe(operator())`.

In `ngrx/store` the new syntax is `store.pipe(select())` and you'll need to import each operator function separately.

```
this.modifyState$ = store.pipe(select('suitablyInfoModify'));
this.client$ = this.modifyState$.pipe(map(data => data.get('client')));
```

Additionally, unless the data returned by your `'suitablyInfoModify'` reducer is a class or object, it's not going to have a `get()` method associated with it. Usually (in all the examples I've seen) ngrx reducers return simple (e.g. json) data. This isn't a requirement though, so your reducer definitely could be returning class instances.

Separately, I don't remember if Angular 6 makes use of rxjs 6 or not, but rxjs 6 also introduced a number of other changes. If you can, upgrading to rxjs 6 now (while you're already going through the upgrade process anyway) will make your life easier down the road.

Comment: changing to `this.client$ = this.modifyState$.pipe(map(data => data.get('client')));`  still throws the same error: `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

Comment: @KobeLuo sounds like you have no data stored in the `suitablyInfoModify` reducer and you haven't given it an initial state.

Comment: Yep, that is the point! Now it is resolved. However I still found `this.modifyState$.map` function does not transfer any data like the old version. I fulfilled the data transfer in another way.